# Lookbehind conundrum OR maybe groups?

Tags: regex

I am sorry I can't formulate a good question:

This regex should find the word 'period' followed by a whitespace and one digit:

```
period.*(?=\s[0-9]{1})|alternative
```

If I input the line `TEST 2019 to period 3.csv` the regex matches `period`.

If I input the line `TEST period 3 2019.csv` the regex matches `period 3`.

**My indtended match is `period 3`**

You can se what I mean from this screenshot from regex101:

[image]

For now I have solved it with lookbehind positve like this:

```
(?<=period\s)[0-9]{1,4}|alternative
```

This matches the digit after 'period' and I can just add 'period' for my specific purpose. But I don't understand why I get different matches.

Comment: `.*` is greedy. `(?=\s[0-9]{1})` will thus match the last number it can find, in the first case, it is 3, in the second case, it is 2. If you want to specifically match single digit numbers, then you'd likely prefer using `(?=\s[0-9]\b)`

Comment: Thx @Jerry but in the first case it does not find 3. In the latter case it does? Can you ELI5?

Comment: It's not a matter of finding or not finding. ` 3` is the last occurrence of a space followed by a digit in the first case. ` 2` is the last occurrence of a space followed by a digit in the second case. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry - that makes sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.*` after period, so just remove it in from your regex and write it like this

```
period(?=\s[0-9]{1})|alternative
```

This matches `period` literally which is followed by a whitespace and a number (ensured by your positive look ahead). Also you really don't need to write `{1}` as that's be default and is redundant. Also if you don't want period to match partially in a larger text, use word boundary `\b` before it and change your regex to this,

```
\bperiod(?=\s[0-9])|alternative
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xbTpYH/1)**

Also, your look behind `(?<=period\s)[0-9]{1,4}|alternative` is not correct for matching the text `period` and indeed that look behind will just match the number which is preceded by `period` and one whitespace.

**[Check this Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xbTpYH/2)**

Comment: I clarified my question: I want to match 'period 3'. So based on your demo I have changed my regex to: `\bperiod\s[0-9]{1}|alternative` -So I dont need to look behind :-) - thanks